# Pen on graph paper effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, sketch-app

I'm new to graphic design and everything, but I was wondering if anyone knows how someone would do what's in the image. It's a digital image but has that cool hand drawn look while still being clean. Is it like drawn by hand and scanned in and enhanced in Photoshop or Illustrator, or is it done entirely with like a sketch tablet or something? It looks really cool and I was hoping to replicate something like this for a project I'm working on but can't find much info on ho to do this! Thanks!

[image: Pen on graph paper]

Answer (score 2):

The, albeit slightly banal, answer is you draw it. Whether you choose to draw it

- by hand on paper than scan it,
- with a pressure sensitive tablet,
- with a mouse,
- or some other way,

is entirely up to you. Personally I would draw these in illustrator just like I would have manually drawn it with a ruler and compass on paper, and then loosen the result up. But that might be because I am trained in machine design where everything used to be done that way 25-20 years ago.

[image]

**Image 1**: These are the same image! just with different style and effect aplied. So sketchy and accurate darwing is equal, doing sketchy drawings does not differ form doing nonscketchy drawings

Anyway the point im trying to get across is that the answer depends on more variables than your presenting and as such your question can not be answered. You need to do a bit testing to see what you want to achieve before we can answer your questions conclusively.